# Stream Initial state is ConnectionState.waiting instead of null

Tags: firebase, dart, firebase-authentication, flutter

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart';

final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
final GoogleSignIn _googleSignIn = new GoogleSignIn();

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  static String tag = 'home-page';

  @override
  HomePageState createState() {
    return new HomePageState();
  }
}

class HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  Stream<FirebaseUser> _currentUser;

  Future<FirebaseUser> signInWithGoogle() async {
    print('google signin invoked');

    GoogleSignInAccount googleUser = await _googleSignIn.signIn();
    GoogleSignInAuthentication googleAuth = await googleUser.authentication;
    FirebaseUser user = await _auth.signInWithGoogle(
      accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken,
      idToken: googleAuth.idToken,
    );
    print("signed in " + user.displayName);

    return user;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final lblWelcome = Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Text('Frnds Payment',
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 28.0, color: Colors.green)));

    final btnSignin = new MaterialButton(
        child: const Text('Sign In with Google'),
        onPressed: () {
          print('button clicked');
          _currentUser = signInWithGoogle()?.asStream();
        });
    final txtOutput = new StreamBuilder<FirebaseUser>(
        stream: _currentUser,
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<FirebaseUser> snapshot) {
          switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
            case ConnectionState.none:
            case ConnectionState.waiting:
              return new Center(child: new CircularProgressIndicator());
            default:
              if (snapshot.hasError)
                return new Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
              else
                return new Center(
                    child: new Text('${snapshot.data.displayName}'));
          }
        });

    final body = Center(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[lblWelcome, btnSignin, txtOutput],
      ),
    );

    return Scaffold(body: body);
  }
}
```

I am newbee to Dart, this is my 1st app.
I need to display the Username after the signin is succesful.

Whenever I start the application it goes to ConnectionState.waiting instead of ConnectionState.none.

Also it does not render the textbox with displayname on succesful signin. reloading it does render the display name.

Comment: Why don't you use a `FutureBuilder` instead of `StreamBuilder` with converting the `Future` returned from `signInWithGoogle()` to a `Stream`?

Comment: What data does `AsyncSnapshot` provide. Have you tried printing them for every call?

Comment: FutureBuilder is not working when returning object, it works fine when returing string, Also i need to progress when signin is in progress.

Comment: signInWithGoogle() function is executed on buttonclick, but the AsyncSnapshot is invoked only once in lifecycle, if i soft reload the app, then the user name is displayed in the textbox

Comment: I don't think this makes a difference. all `asStream` does is creating a stream that emits a single event when the underlying future completes and then completes.

Comment: "FutureBuilder is not working when returning object, it works fine when returing string, Also i need to progress when signin is in progress" Would be interesting how it is not working. I don't see how there would be a difference related to "showing progress"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ConnectionState.none` means there is no stream assigned, 
but you have

```
setState(() => _currentUser = signInWithGoogle()?.asStream());
```

this means the `StreamBuilder` subscribed to this stream and waits for events.

Comment: I'd expect it to be a `Stream` initially. The stream then emits values to the subscriber. Removing `?` in `signInWithGoogle()?.asStream();` shouldn't cause errors.

Comment: ya! Removing ? is fine, but im suscribing to StreamBuilder inside on onPressed event right? How its getting suscribed on App starrtup?

Comment: I see now what you mean. Yes, `_currentUser` should be `null` when initially loaded. You might want to wrap `_currentUser = signInWithGoogle()?.asStream();` with `setState(() => _currentUser = signInWithGoogle()?.asStream());`

Comment: wrapping with setState() changed the state after signing in.. Thanks for the answer